# Marker not draggable on Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app, I want the users to provide the latlng they want to go in a Google Map. So, firstly I have created an activity with a button for user to open a google map:

```
    private Button.OnClickListener opengmap = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getString(R.string.T1001_NoGPSDetection),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 
        } else {
            strprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(strprovider);
        }

        **gmap = new GM001MapForAddress(v.getContext(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), R.id.map);
        gmap.initialize();**

        }
    };
```

Then, I have this GM001MapForAddress to initialize the google map, intended to have a draggable marker:

```
public class GM001MapForAddress {
public Context context;
public GoogleMap googleMap;
public MarkerOptions markeroption;
public Marker marker;
public CameraUpdate center;


public Double latitude, longitude;
public Integer id;
public Activity activity;

public GM001MapForAddress(Context context, Double latitude, Double longitude, Integer id) {
    this.context = context;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.id = id;
}

public void initialize() {

    activity = (Activity) context;
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id)).getMap();
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(clickmap);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(dragmarker);
    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).draggable(true));
    if (marker.isDraggable()) {
        System.out.println("HAHA " + latlng);
    }
    marker.setDraggable(true);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(dragmarker);
    center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    googleMap.moveCamera(center);
    googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    googleMap.getFocusedBuilding();

}

public OnMarkerDragListener dragmarker = new OnMarkerDragListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("here1!!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("here2!!");
        LatLng dragPosition = arg0.getPosition();
        double dragLat = dragPosition.latitude;
        double dragLong = dragPosition.longitude;
        System.out.println("halatlng: " + dragLat + " " + dragLong);
        Log.i("info", "on drag end :" + dragLat + " dragLong :" + dragLong);
        arg0.setPosition(dragPosition);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dragPosition).draggable(true));

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("here3!!");

    }
};

public OnMapClickListener clickmap = new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));          
        System.out.println("latdflng: " + point);
    }
};
```

I have my clickmap listener work but the dragmarker listener never works. I have worked on this for the entire weekend (I am in Asia). So, hopefully somebody can give me a hand on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't drag the marker or you just don't get the callbacks in `dragmarker`?

Comment: hi, i cannot drag the marker

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To enable the drag mode you need to long click on the marker, and then drag while holding.

If the marker is small it can be pretty hard clicking at the right point, if you have clumsy fingers like me.

Comment: forgot to mention that I am testing on an emulator, so the mouse-click should be able to perform the drag and drop.

Comment: @kwytse it's a bad idea to test maps on the emulator. Aside from that you still need to do a long-click with the mouse. A second or two, without moving the mouse then you start to drag.

Comment: You are absolutely right. How stupid I am! Many thanks!